# How to create documentation using xml - tools? suggestions?

Tags: xml

I would like to create documentation using standard xml.  I would like to stay away from Microsoft Word but be able to create documents and procedures using xml. I actually tried to create something simple with Word just to test and then saving it as xml.  The amount of information saved is ridiculous. I want something much simpler and that allows me to go back and edit the files using just Notepad++ or similar.  With an xml file created by Word, the structure is so complex that I am stuck using Word.
Are there tools available that can help me do that?
I am currently doing the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<books>
  <title name="Sample document">
   <author>Insert Author</author>
    <chapter name="Title of the chapter one">
  <content></content>
</chapter>
  </title>
</books>
```

I am just making up the fields as I go but if there is a tool that can automatically do that, it would save me a lot of time and.. I don't want to reinvent the wheel.

Suggestions are appreciated.

Thanks
Tony

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not really a programming question, but take a look at [DocBook](http://www.docbook.org/). You can either use the DocBook Schemas/DTDs as-is or use them for a base and modify to fit your needs.

I would also suggest using an XML editor. [oXygen](http://www.oxygenxml.com/) has built in support for DocBook.

---

### **EDIT**

Almost forgot about [DITA](http://docs.oasis-open.org/dita/v1.2/os/spec/DITA1.2-spec.html). (Also see http://dita.xml.org/)

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is still in development and I have only looked at it superficially, but Jquery-docs is what the Jquery project is working on using for documentation, and it is XML based: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-docs